# Ubuntu 17.10: Too many errors from stdin

Tags: 17.10

I have a VM under Ubuntu 17.10 and I'm having some trouble: I'm getting the following message every time when I'm using nano / etc.:

Too many errors from stdin

I'd try google it, but can't find solution. Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"using nano / etc."*

Comment: It had been solved by itself. Magic Linux, magic Linus!

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible reason...

I just had the same problem in a script running a script executing nano using the command

```
exec nano filename &
```

The solution was to remove the & at the end of the line as nano won't display if asked to run in the background